# GWT and JSNI - Missing qualifier on instance method

Tags: gwt, jsni, gwt-dev-mode

I'm debugging and developing a GWT module through Development Mode. While starting DM I get the following JSNI error: "Missing qualifier on instance method". But, when I compile it, I get no compilation errors. Is it a DM issue or just my fault?

Tip: This is the function I'm trying to access inside native method:

```
public static native void fbLogin () /*-{
    @pack1.pack2.pack3::someMethod(Ljava/lang/String;)(param);
}-*/;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is `someMethod` static or not?

Comment: As @ThomasBroyer said make it static,So no need to create an instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have either, to declare `someMethod` as `static` or to pass the instance object to your jsni block:

```
public static native void fbLogin (pack3 instance) /*-{
   instance.@pack1.pack2.pack3::someMethod(Ljava/lang/String;)(param);
}-*/;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `static` in the method which JSNI function is calling, 
the  Java method should be

```
public static void someMethod(String param){
}
```